# Why default value is needed when variable is annotated with @required?

Tags: dart

```
void main() {
  foo(bar: 1);
}

void foo({@required int bar}) {} // Error
```

Error:

> The parameter 'bar' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, and no non-null default value is provided.

I am annotating `bar` with `@required` and it is also non-nullable. That means I'll always have to provide `bar` a non-null value. So, why does the compiler ask me to provide a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@required` is the old annotation tag coming from the `meta` package and was introduced as a way to give warnings from the analyzer. With NNBD this has been changed to a keyword called `required`. You can read more about this keyword in the following link:

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters